# Computer vision - 2D Convolution with Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Yesterday I saw an exercise with the related solution.
**The text:**

> Your code will take an input tensor input with shape (n, iC, H, W) and a kernel kernel with shape (oC, iC, kH, kW ). It needs then to apply a 2D convolution over input, using kernel as kernel tensor and no bias, using a stride of 1, no dilation, no grouping, and no padding, and store the result in out. Both input and kernel have dtype torch.float32

**The solution:**

```
#set-up code
import random
import torch

n = random.randint(2, 6)
iC = random.randint(2, 6)
oC = random.randint(2, 6)
H = random.randint(10, 20)
W = random.randint(10, 20)
kH = random.randint(2, 6)
kW = random.randint(2, 6)

input = torch.rand(n, iC, H, W, dtype=torch.float32)
kernel = torch.rand(oC, iC, kH, kW, dtype=torch.float32)

#solution code
oH, oW = H-(kH-1), W-(kW-1)
out = torch.zeros((n, oC, oH, oW), dtype=torch.float32)

for i in range(oH):
    for j in range(oW):
         inp = input.unsqueeze(1)[:, :, :,i: i+kH, j : j+kW] # shape inp => (n, 1, iC, H, W)
         ker = kernel.unsqueeze(0) # shape ker => (1, oC, iC, kH, kW)
         out[:, :, i, j] = (inp*ker).sum((-1, -2, -3)) #??
```

My question is:
Why we make the unsqueeze() in this manner?

I know how unsqueeze() works but I can't figure out the problem we solve with this unsqueeze().

Just for a visual reference of the convolution:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)?

Comment: @jodag I learned it just one week ago but yes, I know how broadcasting works

Comment: Multiplying a tensor of shape `[n, 1, iC, kH, kW]` by a tensor of shape `[1, oC, iC, kH, kW]` will result in a tensor of shape `[n, oC, iC, kH, kW]` via broadcasting semantics. Also your comment that `inp` is shape `[n, 1, iC, H, W]` is wrong. It's actually taking a slice of the input of shape `[n, 1, iC, kH, kW]`

Comment: @jodag Yes, obviuosly...sorry, it was my careless mistake. I confused inp whit the result of unsqueeze().

Maybe I don't got this point: The multiplication perform implicitly also the broadcasting? If the answer will be yes then I solved my problem.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the multiplication is implicit exactly. `inp*ker` is an explicit multiplication that invokes broadcasting. For example if `inp` is shape `[9,1,5,6,7]` and `ker` is shape `[1,8,5,6,7]` then the result of multiplication `prod = inp*ker` will have shape `[9,8,5,6,7]`. Specifically, `prod[i, j, :, :, :]` will be equal to `inp[i,0,:,:,:] * ker[0,j,:,:,:]` for all `i` in `range(9)` and all `j` in `range(8)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @jodag I think I understand: the shape of the result of multiplication will be the result of the broadcasting between the shapes of the two tensors involved in the multiplication, I'm right?

P.S.: I don't know if it's necessary to tag you on every comment :')

Answer (score 0):

So a bit of elaboration on the comment I made.

First, if we unroll this ALL the way, we can represent this convolution operation with the following septuple nested for-loop.

```py
out = torch.zeros((n, oC, oH, oW), dtype=torch.float32)
for out_i in range(oH):
    for out_j in range(oW):
        for b_idx in range(n):
            for out_ch in range(oC):
                for in_ch in range(iC):
                    for ker_i in range(kH):
                        for ker_j in range(kW):
                            out[b_idx, out_ch, out_i, out_j] += \
                                input[b_idx, in_ch, out_i + ker_i, out_j + ker_j] \
                                * kernel[out_ch, in_ch, ker_i, ker_j]
```

Of course this is probably going to be pretty slow. Instead we can aggregate the inner three for-loops into a single operation that takes a `kH` by `kW` slice of the input tensor spanning all the input channels and multiply that by a slice of the kernel at the desired output channel.

```py
out = torch.zeros((n, oC, oH, oW), dtype=torch.float32)
for out_i in range(oH):
    for out_j in range(oW):
        for b_idx in range(n):
            for out_ch in range(oC):
                # input_slice -> [iC, kH, kW]
                input_slice = input[b_idx, :, out_i:out_i+kH, out_j:out_j+kW]
                # kernel_slice -> [iC, kH, kW]
                kernel_slice = kernel[out_ch, :, :, :]
                out[b_idx, out_ch, out_i, out_j] = (input_slice * kernel_slice).sum()
```

Observe that in this latest version the `input_slice` is taken from a single batch index (`b_idx`) and the `kernel_slice` is taken from a single output channel (`out_ch`). We compute all combinations of `b_idx` and `out_ch` to fill the output. When we see this type of pattern then [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) should come to mind.

First, if we just took the input slice over all the batches (e.g. `input[:, :, out_i:out_i + kH, out_j:out_j + kW]`) then this would be a `[n, iC, kH, kW]` tensor. And since the kernel is shape `[oC, iC, kH, kW]` these can't be broadcasted together because they don't agree in the first dimension. To deal with this we need to insert some unitary dimensions so they agree everywhere where both have non-unitary dimensions.

Since we want the output of the broadcasted product to be reduced and stored in `out` which has shape `[n, oC, ...]`, then we want to insert unitary dimensions as follows:

```py
out = torch.zeros((n, oC, oH, oW), dtype=torch.float32)
for out_i in range(oH):
    for out_j in range(oW):
        # input_slice -> [n, 1, iC, kH, kW]
        input_slice = input[:, :, out_i:out_i+kH, out_j:out_j+kW].unsqueeze(1)
        # kernel_slice -> [1, oC, iC, kH, kW]
        kernel_slice = kernel[:, :, :, :].unsqueeze(0)
        # broadcasted shape [n, 1, ...] times shape [1, oC, ...] -> [n, oC, ...]
        # therefore prod_slice -> [n, oC, iC, kH, kW]
        prod_slice = input_slice * kernel_slice
        # sum over last three channels producing reduced_slice -> [n, oC]
        reduced_slice = prod_slice.sum((-1, -2, -3))
        out[:, :, out_i, out_j] = reduced_slice
```

Note that we could have achieved a valid broadcast by using `.unsqueeze(0)` on the input slice and `.unsqueeze(1)` on the kernel slice. However, this would have resulted in `reduced_slice` being shape `[oC, n]` instead of `[n, oC]` which would have been the transpose of what we wanted to store in `out`.